# Как убрать право Телеграм бота "Manage channel"?

Tags: telegram-bot

Как убрать право Телеграм бота "Manage channel"?
Случайно включил в BotFather а отключить не получается. Пишет "Settings couldn`t be updated".
[image: img]

Что это за ограничение и можно ли его как-то обойти?

**PS**: если имеет значение, использую телеграм тест сервер

Comment: Смогли разобраться? :)

Comment: @gil9red , к сожалению , пока нет :/

Answer (score 0):

Дело в том что разрешение "Manage channel" включается автоматически при выставлении другого разрешения, например, "post in channel". Выключить его отдельно, без отключения остальных - не получится.